# Is there a FireBug equivalent for IE to debug JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am having a real problem fixing some JavaScript in IE. I am sooooo used to using FireBug that anything else is like driving blindfolded.

Is there a tool that can help me look at my code and spot big IE challenges?

Comment: Which version of IE? IE9 has JS debugging tools similar to Firebug I believe.

Comment: I find it funny that so many people answer, but not so many upvote the question. Seems like a very good question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, there is a firebug for IE also... For IE it is called WEB DEVELOPMENT HELPER go to below link..
http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper

Answer (score 4):

Firebug Lite, or the IE Developer Tools are both possible options.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Script Debugger ---  visual interdev

Answer (score 0):

It's nowhere near as good or useful as Firebug, but hit F12 and you get IE's developer tool equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

There is developer tools - in IE8 at least, press F12 or Tools / Developer Tools from the menu. I'm not able to  test of IE9 is the same menu option but it does have it.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 on come with Developer tools built in and are accessed by pressing `F12`. Otherwise you must use the Microsoft Script Debugger (free download) or Firebug Lite.